# Create and Push an App programmatically from another App in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is it possible to create and push an application into Cloud Foundry from a different application that is already running in Cloud Foundry? Essentially I need to do a 'cf push' from within the application.

I saw there's a Cloud Foundry API that I can use (https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/237/apps/creating_an_app.html). Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

The [Cloud Foundry Java Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) is designed for use cases like this. It takes care of negotiating the OAuth2 security used by the CF API and provides nice abstractions for common operations that require multiple CF API calls (e.g. pushing an app, which involves creating app metadata, pushing the bits, and starting the app). I would prefer this option over using Java to shell out to the `cf` CLI, as you get greater control over the CF API and aren't subject the CLI UI to detect success/failure.

There's nothing stopping an app from running on CF from pushing other apps, but the platform doesn't do a lot to help with this either. Specifically, you'll need the address of the CF API endpoint (e.g. http://api.mycf.example.com) to be able to target, authenticate, and deploy apps. But there is no way for an app running on CF to know the API endpoint of the CF it is running on. So you will need to configure the CF API endpoint into the application that will be pushing other apps.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Yes it is possible. Shell out to the CF cli.

The easiest way to do this would be to just include the CF cli in your application and shell out to it to push your app. You'll have to make sure that the binary you use matches the OS where your app is running (most likely Ubuntu 14.04). But that way, you can just provide it with your user's CF credentials and use the `cf push` logic in the CLI.

There is a CloudFoundry API you can use, but I'd advise against it. Trying to authenticate and push a cf app will be tricky. `cf push` does a lot under the hood -- it not only creates the app via the API endpoint you found, but it also uploads application files in an intelligent way, it attaches routes and services to the app, starts the app, polls the CF API for the updates on the status of the staging task, etc. You'd have to implement all of this on your own (not to mention the OAuth2 workflow to get an auth token).

There are some third-party CF libraries you might find useful (depending on the language you are using):

- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cf-nodejs-client

Lastly the CloudFoundry cli is open-sourced (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli). Bear in mind that as discussed above the `push` logic consists of multiple operations, and as such the codebase might be difficult to grok.